# Bridge IEnumerable collection binding it to TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, ienumerable, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have been looking to find the solution to this problem but still, after so much research, I am unable to figure out an elegant solution. Finally, I have decided to ask it here to get an experts opinion.

It's a WPF application where I have created my domain/model classes like:

```
public abstract class Node : Entity
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children => _children.AsEnumerable();

    public void AddChild(Node node)
    {
        _children.Add(node);
    }

    public void RemoveChild(Node node)
    {
        _children.Remove(node);
    }

    public void MoveUp(Node node)
    {
        var index = _children.IndexOf(node);
        Move(index, index - 1);
    }

    public void MoveDown(Node node)
    {
        var index = _children.IndexOf(node);
        Move(index, index + 1);
    }
}
```

According to this domain, `Node` class has a parent-child relationship.

The important point to note here is `Children` collection type is exposed as `IEnumerable` to encapsulate it to avoid undesired changes to my collection. I want to bind this collection to a TreeView control to show N-level of the hierarchy.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ContainerTemplate" 
                          DataType="{x:Type fsx:Node}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<fsx:TreeViewTemplateSelector x:Key="TreeViewTemplateSelector"
                              ContainerTemplate="{StaticResource ContainerTemplate}" />

<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewNodes"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" 
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}">
</TreeView>
```

Imagine, `Nodes` that is bound to TreeView `ItemSource` property is `ObservableCollection` in ViewModel which is getting the data from Model.

I want to allow UI operations like adding and removing nodes and moving them up and down and correspondingly I want to update those operations in my domain object. Now the problem is that since my collection is not `ObservableCollection`, any operations I am performing is not reflected in UI.

Question is how to make it all work instantly showing the operation result on UI as well as updating the domain behind the scene effectively?

Note: I will update the question to provide more details if required!

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `private List<Node> _children = new List<Node>();` by an ObservableCollection?

Comment: `_children` is private and not exposed for binding so no use of changing the type to `ObservableCollection` even

Comment: That doesn't matter. It is inspected at runtime whether it implements INotifyCollectionChanged. You may also remove AsEnumerable, since it doesn't do anything sensible here.

Comment: Just write `public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Node>();`

Comment: Read this [blog](https://ardalis.com/exposing-private-collection-properties-to-entity-framework) and you would know why AsEnumerable is important. Simply, it is to restrict casting to avoid manipulation on the underlying collection.

Comment: Ok, then go ahead and roll your own, non-modifyable observable collection wrapper.

Comment: You mean i need to change my IEnumerable collection to ObservableCollection by all means?

Comment: If there isn't any realistic scenario where the Children collection is modified unexpectedly or without permission, I wouldn't make my life more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Besides that, AsEnumerable does not prohibit casting. Anybody could still call `((List<Node>)node.Children).Add(new Node());`

Comment: I also did. Works fine for me.

Comment: OK, AsEnumerable can also be replaced with AsReadOnly. Anyways, the essential point is to understand if without changing my Model can I use some technique to achieve want I am after.

Comment: You might want to use a [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620(v=vs.110).aspx) as a wrapper around `ObservableCollection<Node> _children`.